# Hibernate generating incorrect MySQL script

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have two `Classes` mapping each one to an `Entity` in `MySQL` database. Whenever I try to map into to DB I got an `MySQL` `Error`

Class Owner:

```
@Entity
public class Owner {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private int idOwner;

    public int getIdOwner() {
        return idOwner;
    }

    public void setIdOwner(int idOwner) {
        this.idOwner = idOwner;
    }
}
```

Class Car with FK:

```
@Entity
public class Car {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private int idCar;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn( name = "idOwner")
    private Owner owner;

    public int getIdCar() {
        return idCar;
    }

    public void setIdCar(int idCar) {
        this.idCar = idCar;
    }

    public Owner getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(Owner owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }
}
```

Code running:

```
EntityManagerFactory f = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("glorious");
EntityManager em = f.createEntityManager();
EntityTransaction t = em.getTransaction();  

t.begin();

Car c = new Car();
Owner o = new Owner();

c.setOwner(o);

em.persist(c);
em.persist(o);

t.commit();


f.close();
em.close();
```

Error:

```
GRAVE: Unsuccessful: alter table .Car add index FK107B43F620606 (idOwner), add constraint FK107B43F620606 foreign key (idOwner) references .Owner (idOwner)
27/05/2014 20:35:01 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport create
GRAVE: Can't create table 'glorious.#sql-2aa_1f8' (errno: 150)
```

- MySQL Version : 5.5.34
- Engine : InnoDB
- Hibernate Dialect : MySQL5InnoDBDialect

I took the script generated by `Hibernate` and tested it directly in phpMyAdmin, it didn't work.

SQL script :

```
alter table .Car add index FK107B43F620606 (idOwner), add constraint FK107B43F620606 foreign key (idOwner) references .Owner (idOwner)
```

If I fix the script by replacing the tables name with , e.g. `Car` or `glorious.Car` than it works. Anyone has an idea?

Comment: When you used phpMyAdmin / the other machine, were they both running the code against the same MySQL database that Hibernate is? `errno: 150` Can be caused by various problems. Both fields not being either both signed or unsigned integers, the constraint failing when added or incorrect storage engine.

Comment: With phpMyAdmin is the same DB and with another machine is another database, but I think this doesn't change much since both MySQL DBs are InnoDB and I'm creating the tables with the same technique (i.e. hibernate) and same code too

Comment: My guess is that there is a relational constraint failing due to existing data. PMA (phpMyAdmin) can ignore this by turning referential integrity checks off when creating the index. Can you try adding the foreign key in PMA using raw SQL rather than via the GUI? You can see the SQL to run in the Hibernate error message.

Comment: Well, I took the SQL generated by Hibernate and got the same error in PMA. Strangely the name from the tables in the script looked like this : .Car and .Owner. I took the dot out and the script worked, and I left the dot but inserted the DB name before it and also worked.

Comment: script generated : alter table .Car add index FK107B43F620606 (idOwner), add constraint FK107B43F620606 foreign key (idOwner) references .Owner (idOwner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. My persistence.xml had the property `default_schema` set to empty. That's why no DB name was appearing before the table's name.